# Set new Props in testcafe for the test case

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, state, react-props, testcafe

I'm using reactJS and testcafe as one of the testing frameworks.

I've a default configuration - 'showCalculatedValue' set to true(it is always passed a prop), for my application component for which the testcafe test case runs fine. 
However, I need to set that config - 'showCalculatedValue' (through props) to false in testcafe and then run another test case.

And yes, that config doesn't require any sort of action to trigger. 
It is all about if you want to have it as a feature or not.

It is just that when 'showCalculatedValue' is set to true, it renders a specific dom element and when it is not, it doesn't render that element.

So my question is, how could I pass in new props in testcafe to set that 'showCalculated' value to false?

Comment: please give some code

Comment: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors
This might help

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how your config works, but I assume that you can modify it on the client side somehow. If so, I suggest you take a look at the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism. Using ClientFunctions, you will be able to run your custom JS-code with TestCafe.
If this does not help, please share a sample project with a detailed explanation with us.